# Which html5 element for centered viewport

Tags: html

I want to make use of the semantics of the html grouping elements as much as possible.

I am struggling with the right element name for a viewport that centers my whole page in the middle of the screen (only horizontally).

My current solution is this:

```
<section id="viewport">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main data-ng-controller="shell as vm">
        <img alt="logo" src="/content/images/midbody.png" />
        <aside data-ng-show="vm.isBusy" class="page-splash dissolve-animation">
            <div data-cc-spinner="vm.spinnerOptions"></div>
        </aside>
        <article data-ng-view class="contentpage"></article>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer">Webdesign by Patrick Peters</div>
    </footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html elements are about semantic. While `footer`, `header` or `aside` imply somehow that `header` is at the beginning `footer` at the end and `aside` somewhere else, they main purpose is not about telling how their layout is, but to describe the *importance*  and what they are about.

Because of that there is no *equivalent*  for a `centered` element, because `centered` is only a visual information. And the visual representation belongs to `css`.

So if `section` fits use section. You have a `header` and a `footer` so it is a `section` somehow, but as it is the whole page that is represented by `body` there is no real need to wrap it into a `section` (it does not make the structuring clearer).  If it has no semantic meaning you can stay with `div` as an *anonymous* container.

**[whatwg: section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element)**

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.
>
> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information.
>
> *Note*: The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. **A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline**.

**[whatwg: body](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element)**

> The body element represents the main content of the **document**.

Comment: Yes, your last paragraph says it all: because centering does not have any semantics, then use DIVs, and that is what I did. Let's wait if there are more comments of other users ;-)

Comment: @PatrickPeters added the description from the specs, the _Note_ is relatively clear.